# ¿como comparar fechas de un arreglo?

Tags: php, date

Buenas tardes tengo el siguiente arreglo de fechas

```
$fecha = array('2020-02-09', '2020-03-09', 'Sin fecha', '2020-04-09');
$fecha_final ="";
```

lo que quiero conseguir es comparar las 4 para obtener la fecha mas grande entre ellas y guardarla en una variable fecha final.

Pensé en meterlo en un for de la siguiente manera

```
 for ($i = 0; $i < count($fecha); $i++) {           
      $datetime1 = date_create($fecha[0]);
      $datetime2 = date_create($fecha[1]); 
                        }
```

e ir comparado una por una pero todavía no aterrizo bien la idea, espero puedan ayudarme

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Te recomiendo el dato de sin fecha reemplazarlo por el "0000-00-00":

```
$fecha = array('2020-02-09', '2020-03-09', '0000-00-00', '2020-04-09');
$fecha_final = max($fecha);
echo $fecha_final;
```

Si no deseas eliminar el dato 'Sin fecha' del array esta seria otra opción:

```
$fecha = array('2020-02-09', '2020-03-09', 'Sin fecha', '2020-04-09');
$fecha = array_diff($fecha, array('Sin fecha'));
$fecha_final = max($fecha);
echo $fecha_final;
```

Comment: y no se puede remplazar por código el sin fecha? ya que el arreglo que me entregan si lo contiene y hay algunos ejemplos en los que el arreglo esta lleno de puros sin fecha y ahí marca error con la segunda opción que me das